# Sharepoint Web Part - Send row of data to another web part to set default value in an inline edited field

Tags: web-part, sharepoint-designer

#### Introduction

We have one sharepoint 2010 site which houses two Lists, for this example lets say Countries and Cities. In the Cities list we have a lookup for the ID of the Country and also the Title of the country to make that relationship. We want to use sharepoint designer to create a view between these two lists.

1. To show one country details at a time (paged). So we can look through the different countries.
2. Another web part to show related Cities in that Country
3. Allow inline editing on the cities web part with the default value of the select field to be the name of the country currently selected.

#### What we have at the moment

We have achieved all but number 3, i dont understand how to set the default value of a select field using sharepoint designer.

We have tried to use some third party web parts but they dont seem to be cutting the mustard. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

I have found a solution!
If you take a look at this link: [Link](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/sharepointdesigner/using-javascript-to-manipulate-a-list-form-field) you will need to decide on the field that required the selected value to have a default value and also specify the name of a Parameter where the ID that you want to be the default value.

This works and as long as you have set up the relationship it should work.